# authenticationDatabase error when running mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

when doing the m103 mongodb course i came across this error when doing the import lab:

```
user@NHTTPR# mongoimport /dataset/products.json -h localhost:27000 -u m103-application-user -p “m103-application-pass” --authenticationDatabase admin --db applicationData --drop --collection products
```

> 2021-04-07T06:19:23.616+0000    **error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-256": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution was to put **single quotes (')** around the password. instead of double quotes ( or remove the quotes around the password entirely)

mongoimport /dataset/products.json -h localhost:27000 -u m103-application-user -p 'm103-application-pass' --authenticationDatabase admin --db applicationData --drop --collection products
2021-04-07T06:20:25.025+0000    connected to: mongodb://localhost:27000/
2021-04-07T06:20:25.026+0000    dropping: applicationData.products
2021-04-07T06:20:25.423+0000    9966 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
user@NHTTPR#

Answer (score 0):

use single quote or dont use any quotes following works

```
mongoimport --username m103-application-user --password m103-application-pass --port=27000 --authenticationDatabase admin --db applicationData --drop --collection products /dataset/products.json
```